# Aligning equal sign with sum

Tags: align, luatex

Consider following example:
`

```
        \documentclass[bibliography=totoc,toc=sectionentrywithdots,DIV=10, parskip=half, 12pt, captions=tableheading]{scrartcl}     
     \usepackage{amsthm,amsmath,amssymb}
\begin{align*}  
       \begin{split}
         &\mathbb{P}() \\ &=\mathbb{P}()\\ &= \sum\limits_{k=0}^{j} \mathbb{P}()
       \end{split}
\end{align*}`
```

How can I get the equal sign in front of the sum exact under the equal sign in front of the probability?

Comment: [Welcome to TEX.SE!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436/82917) In a minimal setting (loading `amsmath` and `amssymb`) the equal signs _are_ exactly aligned. It this does not happen for you then please provide a full [minimal working example](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228/82917) which reproduces the issue, starting with `\documentclass{...}` and ending with `\end{document}`.

Comment: Do you see the problem?

Comment: @Simon No, if I add \begin{document} and \end{document} to you code, the equal signs *are* exactly aligned.

Comment: @Simon Can you show your requirement in images, not able to understand the requirement exactly...

Comment: Is it possible to create an extra space between the sum and the equal sign? I deal with the same question.